# CLPlacemark crash in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, clgeocoder, clplacemark

I'm using `CLGeocoder` for reverse geolocation and get array of `CLPlacemark`. When I use GPS outside the US (i.e. -27,127) and then access `placemark.postalCode`, the app crashes with:

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

It seems, that `placemark.postalCode` is `nil` where no postal code is available. But `postalCode` return type in Swift is `String!`:

`var postalCode: String! { get } // zip code, eg. 95014`

So I can't even test is for `nil`, because the crash is caused by the getter of `postalCode`.

Any ideas how to prevent this crash? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being an optional, even if implicitly unwrapped, you can check it for nil:

```
if placemark.postalCode != nil {

}
```

and the app won't crash because of that :)

To prove it, just try this code in a playground, where 2 implicitly unwrapped properties (a computed and a stored) are checked for nil:

```
struct Test {
    var nilComputed: String! { return nil }
    var nilStored: String! = nil
}

var test = Test()

if test.nilComputed != nil {
    print("It's not nil")
} else {
    print("It's nil")
}

if test.nilStored != nil {
    print("It's not nil")
} else {
    print("It's nil")
}
```