# Unable to get postal code from CLGeocoder

Tags: objective-c, clgeocoder

i am trying to get postal code from CLGeocoder but app is crashing with error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'`

here is my code

```
CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *Postalcode = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.postalCode];
             NSLog(@"Postal : %@",Postalcode);
```

output is "null"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLPlacemark crash in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671435/clplacemark-crash-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `placemark.postalCode` before you pass to init for `NSString`
Check if it is nil.